# Performance of $firebase() versus new Firebase() on large data objects?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

using angularfire with large data sets, what kind of a performance difference is there between using a $firebase() 2-way data-bound object and JS-API new Firebase() data-reference object?

Answer (score 7):

The $firebase call will begin synchronizing all data immediately, so it is an expensive operation, and it should only be used at the granularity of the data you want to access.

The new Firebase() call merely creates a new reference -- it doesn't actually load data or do any I/O, so it is an extremely cheap call.

Comment: To expand on this, $firebase is more equivalent to calling `new Firebase(URL).on('value')` than it is to `new Firebase(URL)`, which simply instantiates the local Firebase API.